# Xcode Changes Contraints Of Layout By Itself After Reopening The Project

Tags: xcode

I set the constraints of layout properly and also tested it on every device. But the next time I open the project, Xcode just ruined the constraints totally. [image]

How did this happen?

Comment: check your size classes .May be they have been changed

Comment: have your problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the project has a problem and for some reason it is not saving the changes. I have indeed put this solution on my troubleshooting book about Xcode from Apress (shameless advertising... ). I have seen this before.

Backup your project and try this:

1. Quit Xcode
2. Using finder, right click on the `.xcodeproj` file of your project and select `Show Package Contents`.
3. delete everything from that except the file `project.pbxproj`.
4. open the project again fix the constraints and see if the changes are saved the next time you open Xcode.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your solution.

Comment: I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify you Xcode version, but my own experiences with code, that is developed using Xcode 8 Beta 1 to Beta 6: The problem may be caused by bug in XCode.

The explanation, **if you use Xcode 8 Beta**, could be:

- New Xcode offers new storyboard-display logic, that shows different difficulties still in Beta 6
- After fixing both constraints and frames automatically / manually, warnings come back again after reopening project
- This problem moves from Xcode Beta 2 to Beta 6 after my own researches

Let's give Apple a little more time to fix the issues and let's wait until Apple releases GM Seed. It's only beta though